# How to have no digit after . with CurrencyStyle

Tags: swift

I am working with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle`. Is there a way to display the amount like this: $0 and not $0.00

My code:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_us")
println("en_us \(formatter.stringFromNumber(0))")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` so that it's a currency.

Then use the formatter's `setMaximumFractionDigits` with an argument of 0. Since MaximumFractionDigits determines how many digits go after the decimal point, setting it to zero should give you what you're looking for.